# Java - class loading results in ClassNotFoundException for parent class

Tags: java, classloader

I am currently making a small plugin framework for a program in Java.
Basically `GRPluginManager.loadPlugins()` loops trough all jar files in a directory, then reads the name of the Main-class of this plugin from a specific file inside of the jar and loads it into the classpath. After that it calls the `enable()` method of this plugin-Main-class (which extends `GRPlugin`).

However, it doesn't work. It looks like the loading of the plugin-Main-class works fine and only the parent class (`GRPlugin`) can not be found.  But it definitely exists.

*GRPlugin.java*

```
package io.github.grengine.core.plugins;

public class GRPlugin {

    public void enable(){

    }

    public void disable(){

    }
}
```

*GRPluginManager.java*

```
package io.github.grengine.core.plugins;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader;
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

import io.github.grengine.JarUtils;
import io.github.grengine.Log;
import io.github.grengine.Main;

public class GRPluginManager {

    private static final String PLUGIN_PATH = Main.main.getDataFolder()+File.separator+"storage"+File.separator+"plugins";
    private ArrayList<GRPlugin> plugins = new ArrayList<GRPlugin>();

    public ArrayList<GRPlugin> loadPlugins() throws Exception{

    File filePath = new File(PLUGIN_PATH);
    File files [] = filePath.listFiles();

    //Iterate over files in the plugin directory

    for(File file:files){
        if(file.isFile()){

            Log.Info("Reading "+file);

            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);


            String fullyQualifiedName = null;
            String plname = null;
            String plversion = null;

            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                ZipEntry ze = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();
                if(ze.getName().equals("gre"+File.separator+"ext.yml")){
                    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
                    InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(ze);
                    Map<?, ?> map = (Map<?, ?>) yaml.load(is);

                    fullyQualifiedName = (String) map.get("main");
                    plname = (String) map.get("name");
                    plversion = (String) map.get("version");
                }
            }


            zipFile.close();


            Log.Info("Enabling "+plname+" "+plversion+" ...");

            URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { new URL("file:"+file) });


            Class<?> clazz = classLoader.loadClass(fullyQualifiedName);
            GRPlugin pl = (GRPlugin) clazz.newInstance();
            pl.enable();

Log.Info("Enabling "+plname+" "+plversion+" ...");

        }else {
         //skip folders
         continue;
       }
    }
    return plugins;
    }

}
```

And the Main class of the plugin (the class extending `GRPlugin`) / *Main.java*

```
package io.github.plutos;

import io.github.grengine.Log;
import io.github.grengine.core.plugins.GRPlugin;

public class Main extends GRPlugin{

    @Override
    public void enable() {
        Log.Info("ENABLED");

    }

    @Override
    public void disable() {
        Log.Info("DISABLED");

    }

}
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/github/grengine/core/plugins/GRPlugin
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:798) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at io.github.grengine.core.plugins.GRPluginManager.loadPlugins(GRPluginManager.java:82) ~[?:?]
        at io.github.grengine.Main.onEnable(Main.java:56) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:321) ~[spigot-core.jar:git-Spigot-c5146ba-c637b93]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:340) [spigot-core.jar:git-Spigot-c5146ba-c637b93]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot-core.jar:git-Spigot-c5146ba-c637b93]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:356) [spigot-core.jar:git-Spigot-c5146ba-c637b93]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:316) [spigot-core.jar:git-Spigot-c5146ba-c637b93]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.s(MinecraftServer.java:418) [spigot-core.jar:git-Spigot-c5146ba-c637b93]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.k(MinecraftServer.java:382) [spigot-core.jar:git-Spigot-c5146ba-c637b93]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:337) [spigot-core.jar:git-Spigot-c5146ba-c637b93]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:256) [spigot-core.jar:git-Spigot-c5146ba-c637b93]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:528) [spigot-core.jar:git-Spigot-c5146ba-c637b93]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.grengine.core.plugins.GRPlugin
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:798) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_05]
        ... 25 more
```

I just can't find a solution for this problem, I already tried different ClassLoaders (`ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` and `GRPlugin.class.getClassLoader()`) ...

Can you tell what i am doing wrong? If you need more information, feel free to ask!

Thanks in advance,
fusionlightcat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't set a parent classloader to your custom classloader, the system classloader will be used as parent by default.

It seems that in your environment `GRPlugin` is loaded by a descendant of the system classloader and hence the error.

Use this instead:

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { new URL("file:"+file) }, GRPlugin.class.getClassLoader());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see plugin system implementation in [ipscan](https://github.com/angryziber/ipscan) open source project. Here is start points for exploration:

- main [Plugin](https://github.com/angryziber/ipscan/blob/master/src/net/azib/ipscan/core/Plugin.java) interface. Any of plugins in ipscan must implement it.
- [PluginLoader](https://github.com/angryziber/ipscan/blob/master/src/net/azib/ipscan/core/PluginLoader.java) class is your `GRPluginManager` analog. It loads plugins from different places (in project jar, external jars etc.) Look here implementation of `PluginClassLoader` which extends `URLClassLoader` and loads classes from jar files.
- [feeders](https://github.com/angryziber/ipscan/tree/master/src/net/azib/ipscan/feeders) folder with some inproject plugins which implemented `Plugin` interface.

**UPDATE:** also you can reuse for your plugin system standard [java.util.ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) or some [alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7237152/2313177)